# Output to Word Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, output

Good morning Stackers,
This community has been nothing but help so today .. my dilemma

Right now I have this to output directly to a preformatted outlook window

```
Dim Outl As Object
Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim omsg As Object
    omsg = Outl.CreateItem(0)
    omsg.To = IncidentCommander
    omsg.bcc = "ICTimeline@nshs.edu"
    omsg.subject = "Timeline for " + CStr(IncidentName) + " - " + CStr(incprob) + " #" + CStr(IncidentNumber) + " - " + " Date: " + D + vbCrLf
    omsg.body = TimeLine.Text
    omsg.Display(True) 'will display message to user
End If
```

I need to convert that from outputting to an outlook with those parameters to outputting to a MS Word doc with the same parameters.  I am open to either the direct code replcaing my outlook objet. or some insight.. Thanks in advance!

Also

What is the syntax for If X OR Y OR Z then

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55685/Word-Automation-using-VB-NET-Part-I) a while back (Last Month :p).

It details a pretty straightforward approach to working with word documents. However, you would need to convert the text manually (and create an object for it), but being that you only have text it shouldn't really be an issue.

Hopefully that will work for you, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

You sort of answered your own question, since that is the syntax for an if statement using "Or":

```
If X OR Y OR Z then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Unless you're referring to something else? There is also the "Or" bitwise operator.